# Send broadcast from one apk/package to another apk/package

Tags: android, package, broadcast

I need to send broadcast from my one application to another applicaion.. any help! 
my application package are 1)com.demo.database and 2)com.demo.list

```
 Intent themesIntent = new Intent(ThemesManager.THEMES_UPDATED);
 themesIntent.putExtra("package", packageName);
 ctx.sendBroadcast(themesIntent);
```

not working..

Edits :

```
<receiver android:name="com.sample.ThemesUpdatedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sample.THEMES_UPDATED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Have you declared the `BroadcastReceiver` in `com.demo.list` in it's `AndroidManifest.xml` file, or just in the code? Because it MUST be in the `AndroidManifest.xml` for it to work between apps.

Comment: yeah, it's there with intent filter

Comment: one important thing is com.demo.list has no LAUNCHER activity.. not sure that can make any difference

Answer (score 5):

@Ajit: Hi, Since Android API 3.0 [API level 11], If an application has never been started even once, then it's BroadcastReceiver can't receive events.As, in your case, your app has no launcher activity, so may be it is the case that causes rejection of event.

Along with that please try using below approach:
You have passed that constant value while creating Intent object. Instead pass it in method intent.setAction();

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I figured that every sent broadcast is received by all applications except when you setPackage to the sending intent for specific package broadcast.

I am not receiving broadcast because my another app is not launched(that doesn't have launcher activity).

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to broadcast, it generally follows you have a sender and receiver. You've posted what looks like the sender ..

sender (where ever you're sending from):

```
Intent toret = new Intent();
toret.setAction("com.myapp.foo");
toret.putExtra("bar", "fizzbuzz");
sendBroadcast(toret);
```

receiver (in eg `onResume()`)

```
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.myapp.foo");
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // ... do something with the intent
        }
    // register the receiver
    this.registerReceiver(receiver , intentFilter);
```

Sender always sends, receiver needs to register to listen for the intent.

Comment: yup, registered in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: OK, so what's in the XML ? (and what's the THEMES_UPDATED constant's value ? )

Comment: added edits, and yes THEMES_UPDATED is constant value