# How to close application from another application in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two android applications. i start activity from App1 and when App2 activity finish i get results in App1 onActivityResult(). 
Now what i want that if i already open App2 activity and it is not finish yet and if i get some request in App1 to close the App2 activity then i close it without returning any result.

What i did, if i send intenet to "close_activity" signal to App2 activity  from App1 like that:

```
 Log.i(TAG, "stoping app..");
    try {

        Intent intent = mContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.company.communicationApp");
        intent.setAction("CANCEL_CALL");
         context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable stop app", e);
    }
```

I guess only one way to send intenet to a running activity with this way. so this will again start new activity. App2 activity is not a singleTask because if i set it as a singleTask i unable to get results in App1 onActivityResult when App2 activity finish().
 Any hint how i can close the current running activity.

-----------------------------With BroadcastReceiver----------------------

in App1 activity sending intent as broadcast:

```
   try {
        final Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("CANCEL_CALL");
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.hos.hp.talk", "com.hos.hp.talk.MainActivity"));

        mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable stop communication app", e);
    }
```

in App2 i have register BroadcastReceiver as:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("CANCEL_CALL");
    registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);

}
 private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("ddd");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i solve this issue. For sending intent:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.hp.walk.CLOSE_APPLICATION");
    getApplication().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

in another application this is how i register receiver to get intent:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("com.hp.walk.CLOSE_APPLICATION");
    registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);



 private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("com.hp.walk.CLOSE_APPLICATION".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Log.i(TAG, "received.. ");
            finish();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the Broadcast Receiver

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: ok. But is it possible to sendBroadcast(Intent) from one app to another ?

Comment: @user526206, yes, your the app receiving the broadcast must be running, but yes it is totally possible from what I've read.  Seaching Stackoverflow returns several posts describing the process.  For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304329/send-broadcast-from-one-apk-package-to-another-apk-package

Comment: Sorry it is not working. both application are running but i unable to get intent in app2. I updated my question with BroadcastReceiver... Can you please give me hint where i doing wrong ?